# Remove directory in ftp

Tags: osx, ftp, rm

This is probably very simple, but I really can't get it to work. I have an old directory with a symlink in it. I need to delete the directory, but it says it is not empty when I try:

```
rm -f dirname
```

(I have also tried `-r`, and `-rf`)

I get: "`usage: rmdir directory-name`"

So then I try `rmdir -f dirname`, but I get the same response.

Comment: What OS?  You are claiming you get a `rmdir` message by running `rm`.  What travesty has been inflicted on your `rm`?  Try `type rm`.

Comment: As @jw013 says, an `rmdir` error from `rm` proper is odd. Try `/bin/rm -r dirname`.

Comment: Everyone, OP is trying to delete from inside a ftp client, not the Unix command shell. I tagged the question with `osx` and `ftp` and edited the question header, but the edit has to be approved first before it shows.

Comment: If usage is `rmdir directory-name` then it isn't asking for any args, so -f would be inappropriate. Try `rmdir dirname`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

(1) did you check the directory to make sure it's really empty? Did you look for hidden files   with

`ls -a`?

hidden files: files with a name that start with  `.` and don't show with regular `ls`. If you do find some, delete them and try your command again.

(2) try `rm -fR dirname`

Comment: I'm on a Mac using terminal to ftp. I tried 1 & 2. There are no hidden files. When I try 2, I still get "usage: rmdir directory-name"

Comment: @user19993 re "on a Mac using terminal to ftp" .. is this osx, and just to be sure, you are trying to delete the directory not via ftp, but on your Mac in one of your directories, right?

Comment: I am on a mac OSX. I have connected to my ftp via terminal - in an attempt to delete this directory because I cant seem to do it via FTP programs or web interface.

Comment: @user19993 Ok, thanks that's helpful, I added a OSX tag to your question. I am still a bit unclear about how/where you are trying to delete the file. What is your prompt, is it a regular terminal prompt or something like `ftp>`?

Comment: I am connected to my Dreamhost ftp account via terminal for Mac. I have a directory in this account that used to hold a wordpress install. I deleted the files within, but the wp-content folder is still there with a symbolic link inside. I want to remove this entire directory, but I cant. I assume the best (most powerful) way to do this was via command line. However, I cant seem to get the force remove commands to work. I hope this helps - again I'm pretty new to this so sorry if I'm missing something here. And yes the prompt is ftp>

Comment: @user19993 Ok, I guess my main question boils down to: Are you inside the ftp program when you are trying to delete this directory? Is your prompt `ftp>` or something similar? If not, can you tell me what your prompt looks like? (I wish I had a mac so that I was more familiar with osx - I'm quite comfy with all other types of unix/linx systems :)

Comment: @user19993 and what exactly is the error message? You posted the usage message that comes with it,but there should have been something else too, if you can post that too it might help.

Comment: my prompt looks like "ftp>"

Comment: @user19993 Great, that's good information!! How did you start this program, did you just type `ftp`? Can you tell me what it displays when it starts? Ie full name + version. I bet you have hidden files there, but your ftp client is not showing them. We'll get this deleted with a bit more information.

Comment: there is no error I try to enter something like rm -f wp-content and all I get is "usage: rmdir directory-name" and when I try rmdir wp-content I get "directory is not empty" So I try rmdir -f wp-content and I get "usage: rmdir directory-name" again.

Comment: to start I entered ftp > open > ftp location > credentials. Now I can see my home directory which has multiple directories within. I want to delete two of directories within the main dir. There are no hidden files within these sub directories, but even if there were, shouldn't there be a command that will remove all within? I guess I just dont understand why I cant force remove.

Comment: @user19993 thanks for all the info. There are several ftp clients, I am trying to figure out which one you are using, so when you type ftp there has to be some startup/copyright message telling you this info - is that the case? Alternatively, do  you have access to a FTP client that's GUI based, if so please tell me exactly what the name of that tool is. If I know what specific programs you are using I can probably find out the commands you need.

Comment: For GUI I use Panic Transmit. I tried deleting the files using Transmit, but get errors. So now I'm trying with Mac OSX terminal's command line. Unfortunately, I dont know any more specifics regarding this Mac's ftp. I did not see any startup/copyright message

Comment: Ok, try this [link](http://osxdaily.com/2010/04/19/show-invisible-files-in-transmit-for-mac/) for Transmit, it shows how to make invisible files visible, and perhaps you can make progress that way.

Comment: I already have that option turned on. There is only one file inside my wp-content folder and that is the symbolic link.

Comment: Ok, last suggestion. When you are using the command line tool in ftp, and you are in the directory/folder that contains the symbolic link, can you see it when you list the directory? I know you can with the GUI tool, so you know its name. Either case, even if you can't see it with the command tool, in the directory where this pesky thing is, try `delete sym_linkfilename` (substitute the name you saw in the GUI).

Comment: or `rm symlinkfilename` .. the idea is to get rid of the symlink inside the folder, and then you should be able to remove the folder itself.

Comment: I can see the symbolic link both in the GUI and in the command line. It is not a hidden file because it has a filename before the '.php' extension.  When trying 'delete filename' I get "no such file or directory"  UGHHHHH

Comment: Ok, I'm out of ideas, I'm going to edit the title of your question to contain the fact that you are trying to do this in ftp. You may want to update the text of your question with some of the information you shared with me. Hopefully, that and the fact that I tagged this will help get more eyes on the question.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to come up with a definite answer, but the information we got will hopefully help find the answer. At that point once you [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) you can give me an upvote too by clicking on the little gray up-triangle

Comment: I got it to work using SSH instead of ftp from the terminal. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Awesome! Great job, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can remove the directory, you need to remove the file that's in it.

```
rm testing/name_of_the_symbolic_link
rmdir testing
```

If there are many files, you need to remove them all.

If you want the convenience of familiar command line or GUI file manipulation tools to manipulate files over FTP, you can mount the FTP directory as a filesystem. Some OSes have this feature integrated in their GUI (for example, Ubuntu does as far as I recall); I don't know about OSX. You can mount the FTP directory on the command line using [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/).

```
mkdir ~/mnt
curlftpfs ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path ~/mnt
rm -r ~/mnt/testing
fusermount -u ~/mnt
```

Comment: Thank you! It's the elegant decision for remove dir in FTP!

Answer (score 0):

To find any lagging files under testing/ and get rid of them.

`find testing/ -type f -exec rm -f {} \;`

Sometimes files or symlinks can get created that contain special characters and those can stymie our attempts to remove them using common tools.

Then, do the same for directories:

`find testing/ -type d -exec rm -f {} \;`

After that, testing/ should be empty and you should be able to rmdir it.

Comment: Tim, I am using Mac OSX terminal to connect to ftp to my Dreamhost server. The find command is not available. Again, I plead ignorance on the subject matter.

Comment: ah, you may want to try a graphical ftp client like Transmit (http://www.panic.com/transmit/).  The GUI clients often have implementations of advanced features that are difficult in the old CLI ftp client.

Comment: I have transmit, but when I try to delete the folder or file i get an error. That is why I resulted to the command line.

Comment: Dreamhost has shell access, via SSH, if you enable it for your account.  That would possibly give you better control over that directory.  (http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Enabling_Shell_Access)

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
rmdir -f dirname
```

Comment: Explanation necessary, especially with so many better ideas right there.  Why might this work when others didn't/don't?